# Strange space between letters in math mode

Tags: spacing

I am working with a variable called `VAL` in my LaTeX document. But it behaves strange
in math mode.

Here is an example (I'm using `tabular` to highlight the issue):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Normal italic text: & \textit{VAL} \\
    Math mode text: & $VAL$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered example.]

As you can see, math mode inserted a space between V and A. Why? How can I remove it?

Comment: no, it is text mode that inserts a (negative) space  (kern) so the letters overlap

Comment: if VAL is a word not V times A times L use `\mathit{VAL}`

Comment: You could write `$V\mkern-5mu AL$`, but if you want to type abbreviations or words even in math mode, it would be better to actually use `\mathit`.

Comment: Not elegat but solve the problem: $V\!\!AL$